# How to write a mysql query to get data from like mixed column and rows

Tags: mysql, select

I'd like to query the table which stores the entries somehow mixed in rows and columns.

Here is the table:

```
|  id | class | field | value |
|-----|-------|-------|-------|
|  1  |   1   |   a   |  AA   |
|  2  |   1   |   b   |  BB   |
|  3  |   1   |   c   |  CC   |
|  4  |   2   |   a   |  DD   |
|  5  |   2   |   b   |  EE   |
|  6  |   2   |   c   |  FF   |
```

What should be the query to get a result like:

a)

```
| class | new_a | new_c |
|-------|-------|-------|
|   1   |   AA  |  CC   |
|   2   |   DD  |  FF   |
```

My pseudo query I imagine it would be something like:

```
select class, value(where field=a) as new_a, value(where field=c) as new_c, from table;
```

b)

```
| class | new_a | new_c |
|-------|-------|-------|
|   2   |   DD  |  FF   |
```

For this one I guess it should be like:

```
select class, value(where field=a) as new_a, value(where field=c) as new_c, from table where class = '2';
```

Unfortunatelly I'm rarely using the mysql and I'm not sure how to build this query. All constructive suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Do your result need only two new columns new_a, new_c?

Comment: Yes, I need class, new_a, new_c

Comment: check the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query

For a) The query is

```
SELECT t1.class, t1.value as new_a, t2.value as new_b 
 FROM table t1 
 JOIN table t2 ON(t2.class=t1.class ) 
 WHERE t1.field='a' AND t2.field='c'
```

For b) The query is

```
SELECT t1.class, t1.value as new_a, t2.value as new_b 
 FROM table t1 
 JOIN table t2 ON(t2.class=t1.class ) 
 WHERE t1.field='a' AND t2.field='c' AND t1.class='2'
```

1) you are trying to convert the rows into columns so I joined the same table twice with condition as 2 tables should have same 'class' value
2) then added condition as what to fetch from table t1 and table t2 as t1.field='a' and t2.field='c' 
3) In second query you need only the class value '2', so i added the condtion as t1.class=2

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure how you did it but it works! If you could explain it it would be great. Thanks again!